# npm package's binary accessible until I add flags

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, npm

I'm on a mac am trying to install `elasticdump`. It is also worth noting that I am using zsh, but am getting the equivalent error described below when switching over to bash.

I just re-installed `npm` from scratch and am now using `6.12.0`. After this, I ran `npm install elasticdump -g` which appears to have worked just fine.

```
$ which elasticdump
/usr/local/bin/elasticdump
```

It appears I am still having the same issue I was having before I tried re-installing everything.

I can run `elasticdump` directly with no issues. It tells me I need an `input` and an `output` as I would expect.

```
$ elasticdump
Sat, 09 Nov 2019 04:52:40 GMT | Error Emitted => {"errors":["`input` is a required input","`output` is a required input"]}
```

I can even run it with `--help`.

```
$ elasticdump --help
elasticdump: Import and export tools for elasticsearch
version: 6.15.7
...
```

But when I add an input and output, things fall apart!

```
$ elasticdump \
  --input /Users/slant/Desktop/data.json \
  --output http://localhost:9200/companies \
  --type data
zsh: command not found: elasticdump
```

And in bash:

```
$ elasticdump \
>   --input /Users/slant/Desktop/data.json \
>   --output http://localhost:9200/companies \
>   --type data
bash: elasticdump : command not found
```

I'm completely baffled as to how adding specific flags causes it to become completely inaccessible! Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: In case anyone requests this:

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/elasticdump
lrwxr-xr-x  1 slant  admin  47 Oct  1 20:42 /usr/local/bin/elasticdump -> ../lib/node_modules/elasticdump/bin/elasticdump
```

Accessing the binary through the file directly behaves exactly the same way as using just `elasticdump` by itself.

Updated, for clarification.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/bin/elasticdump
Sat, 09 Nov 2019 18:40:56 GMT | Error Emitted => {"errors":["`input` is a required input","`output` is a required input"]}
```

```
$ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/bin/elasticdump \
  --input /Users/ryan/Desktop/data.json \
  --output http://localhost:9200/companies \
  --type data
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/bin/elasticdump
```

Comment: Did you try to call elasticdump with full path to real file not symlink, for example `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/bin/elasticdump —input ...` ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if my edit wasn't clear enough there. My very last line mentions this, in fact.